# What is the best way to return a string to the SWIG python interface?

Tags: python, c++, string, memory-management, swig

What is a thread-safe and memory-leak-free way to return a string from C++ to the SWIG python interface?

SWIG will automatically copy the contents of a `char *` return value into a python string. [This SWIG guide](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_class_extension) gives the example:

```
char *__str__() {
    static char temp[256];
    /* WRITE STUFF TO STRING */
    return &temp[0];
}
```

Their example uses a static string as a return value, but if my C++ program has multiple threads, they could easily overwrite each other's strings.

Returning a newly allocated string would create a memory leak, since SWIG would not know to free it.

The only thing I can think of is to register and return a pointer to an actual python string object (that way the python garbage collector would take care of it), but I am not sure how to go about that and am wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: What about the tried and true method of having the caller supply the buffer, and the C++ code just copy into that buffer?  That is how, for example, the Windows API handles strings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think that would work with SWIG. First of all, SWIG would only be able to supply a pointer to the raw data of an immutable python string, which would crash python if modified. Second of all, that would violate the interface of methods such as `__str__`, which are not supposed to have any arguments passed to them.

Comment: Have you tried creating a wrapper that returns a std::string?

Comment: @Schollii I tried it, but SWIG does convert `std::string`s to python strings.

Comment: @Matt - `I don't think that would work with SWIG. First of all, SWIG would only be able to supply a pointer to the raw data of an immutable python string`  Then SWIG is severely lacking functionality if there is no way a modifiable buffer can be passed to a function. `Second of all, that would violate the interface of methods such as __str__, which are not supposed to have any arguments passed to them`  Then  maybe you should write a C++ factory class that allocates and returns strings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The reason I am asking this question, is for people that use SWIG who have run into this to share how they solved it. Anyone can right a makeshift workaround, I am simply hoping that I won't have to.

Comment: @Matt you meant "...but SWIG does *not* convert", right? It's been a while but I am quite certain that it does, but you need to include the `std::string` typemaps.

Comment: @Schollii Yes, that is what I meant, sorry for the typo. You should make that an answer to the question, by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SWIG creates wrapper code to convert between C++ `std::string` and Python strings, *if* you include the typemaps defined in `std_string.i`.

Comment: Thanks! I did `%include <std_string.i>`, and it worked!

Comment: Does this handle freeing the std::string if it was created in the C++ method?  Or does %new_object need to be specified on the C++ method?

Comment: @jason Need newobj but not sure, do a side by side diff of generated code with and without the newobj decl, should only show a few lines different.

Comment: So the answer to my comment is that if the `std::string` is created with `new` then it must be manually deleted and swig will do that with `%newobject`.  But if the `std::string` is created with a declaration like `std::string myStr` then C++ handles its lifespan and `%newobject` will not affect the generated code.